# Adding a jQuery script to wordpress Admin

Tags: jquery, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I cannot for some reason get the wordpress /wp-admin pages to execute a simple query file.
It only works if i deregister jquery in my functions.php within my theme folder, but then i must re-register all the jquery.ui files separately which is tedious. Im using wordpress 3.0 multisite installation. I'm trying not to touch the core wp files.

It will show in the source and links to the file ok but won't execute the script.
heres what i have in my functions.php:

```
function my_script() {
if (!is_admin()) {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js', false, '1.4.4');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('custom_script', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/myScript.js', array('jquery'));
}
if(is_admin()){
    wp_enqueue_script('custom_admin_script',  get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/admin_script.js', array('jquery'));
}   }
```

add_action('init', 'my_script');

Here's My jquery file (admin_script.js):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
alert("Hello"); });
```

any help would be great.

Comment: Given I'm never positive it won't be in no conflict, I us this by default as it takes care of it and I can stick to my normal: (function($){ // all my jQuery using $('selectors') })(jQuery);

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Be aware that the jQuery included with Wordpress runs in **NoConflict Mode** as far as I know, meaning that there is no `$`, but instead `jQuery`. That's probably why you deregistered the builtin jQuery and used the one from Google CDN. That one probably doesn't run in that mode.

I don't have any experience with wordpress, so I might make a mistake here. Just be sure that the builtin jQuery is available and load your script.

```
function my_script() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_enqueue_script('custom_script', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/myScript.js', array('jquery'));
    }
    if(is_admin()){
        wp_enqueue_script('custom_admin_script', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/admin_script.js', array('jquery'));
    }   
}
```

Change your admin_script.js to use `jQuery` instead `$`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    alert("Hello"); 
});
```

See if that works for you. If you like to use `$` you could probably write `var $ = jQuery;` at the top of your admin_script.js.

Comment: jQuery actually passes itself as the first argument of the function it calls, so you can write `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { $('#blah').click(); });` etc. Or, of course, just `jQuery(function ($) { $('#blah').click(); });`.

Answer (score 10):

You can do like this

```
<?php add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'function_name' ); ?>
```

This can be used like this

```
<?php 
  add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_script' ); 
  function load_custom_script() {
      wp_enqueue_script('custom_js_script', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/custom-script.js', array('jquery'));
  }
?>
```

For more help see the documentation [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts)