# Adding a jQuery file to wordpress admin

Tags: php, wordpress, function

Using a [past question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927352/adding-a-jquery-script-to-wordpress-admin)....

I would like to add a js file to the admin section of Wordpress.

This is what I have so far:

in my theme **functions.php**

```
function alert_delete() {
    if(is_admin()){
        wp_register_script( 'alert_delete', get_bloginfo('template_url'). '/js/alert_delete.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('alert_delete');
    }   
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'alert_delete');
```

This is not loading the file in the admin section of WP. If I take out the is_admin() condition it will load the file on the frontend.

How to do you enqueue a js file to load in the admin section of WP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add `admin_enqueue_scripts` instead of `wp_enqueue_scripts`

so it should be

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'alert_delete');
```

wp_enqueue_scripts is for the front end.

hope this helps