# Adding jQuery to wp-login.php

Tags: jquery, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm trying to add javascript using jQuery around my wordpress site.

But the code fails on wp-login, saying that jQuery is undefined. I guess this is because a user hasn't logged in and so htaccess is denying them access to loading jquery from the site resources or something.

My question is, how can I either:

- alter wordpress logic so that this library is automatically loaded?
- include this library globally in some way so that there won't be a conflict if it gets included twice
- add code so that I include Google hosted jQuery on this page specifically?

I'm sure someone else must have encountered this issue before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/adding-jquery-scripts-wordpress/) page. Later on on the page this piece of code can be found:

```
function my_theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-great-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-great-script.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_scripts' );
```

You have to insert this code into your `functions.php`.

Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927352/adding-a-jquery-script-to-wordpress-admin) post.

Comment: This gave me what I want, except that I needed to say login_enqueue_scripts instead of wp_enqueue_scripts to get this script to run on the login page.

Comment: Edited, now it fits your purposes :-)